# how do I get this code to take 65 and convert it into binary with c++/cli

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    int base10;
    long base2 = 0;
    base10 = Convert::ToInt32(txtBase10->Text);
    base2 = base10 / 128 * 10000000;
    base10 %= 128;

    base2 = base10 / 64 * 1000000;
    base10 %= 64;

    base2 = base10 / 32 * 100000;
    base10 %= 32;

    base2 = base10 / 16 * 10000;
    base10 %= 16;

    base2 = base10 / 8 * 1000;
    base10 %= 8;

    base2 = base10 / 4 * 100;
    base10 %= 4;

    base2 = base10 / 2 * 10;
    base10 %= 2;

    base2 = base10 / 1 * 1;
    base10 %= 1;
}
```

Comment: What on EARTH are you doing? post the entire function.  Edit - my bad, it was there, but badly formatted.

Comment: Just base2 = base10; Nothing more. All computers stores ALL information in BINARY form. No other ways.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: assuming this is for visual representation.  However, this function doesn't store anything.  It's currently written as a box with a coin slot in it.  You put a coin in, and the box heats up.  Let's pretend that the function does in fact need to do whatever it's doing, and get it doing it well.

Comment: Note that this is C++/CLI, not C++.

Answer (score 3):

You are not understand what is binary form of numbers. If you need to convert any integer to it's STRING represenation you may do following:

```
String base2 = Convert.ToInt32(str,2).ToString();
String base8 = Convert.ToInt32(str,8).ToString();
String base10 = Convert.ToInt32(str,10).ToString();
String base16 = Convert.ToInt32(str,16).ToString();
```

Comment: For a purely representational need, this will work very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as a long and not a String, you can use this as the body of your function, it will perform better:

```
int base10 = Convert::ToInt32(txtBase10->Text);
long base2 = 0;

for (int mask = 0x80; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
{
    base2 *= 10;
    if (base10 & mask) ++base2;
}

// base2 now has the number you want.
```

[Here's an ideone with a brief testing of some values between 0 and 255 (including 65).](http://ideone.com/VevXiX)

Comment: Without "if" inside loop: http://ideone.com/J5fJa1 . But with such way you will get mistake with large numbers.